# What is JSON base64 endode binary data?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2

I need to understand what is JSON base64 encoded binary data? And how to send it from a client (lets say HttpClient) and how do I receive it in Web api2?

Is it Bson(Binary Json)? If not then whats the difference?

Thanks

Comment: Not really. I want to understand that if it is just a JSON object that I convert into a ByteArray and then convert it into Base64String? Or is it something else? What should the web api be expecting as a parameter? The object or byte[]?

Comment: Did you read [this](https://jb64.org/)?